# Ayuda con error de RenderBody MVC

Tags: html, mvc

Tengo el siguiente error

```
The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page
```

Que es debido a que no según no llamo al método `RenderBody()` en mi layout mi codigo html es el siguiente:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" href="~/Recursos/img/fav-icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Sierra</title>
    <!-- Icon css link -->
    <link href="~/Recursos/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="~/Recursos/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Rev slider css -->
    <link href="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/css/layers.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/css/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Extra plugin css -->
    <link href="~/Recursos/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Recursos/vendors/magnify-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="~/Recursos/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Recursos/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>


    <!--================Header Menu Area =================-->
    <header class="main_menu_area">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="service.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown submenu">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Blog
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="single-blog.html">Blog Details</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="elements.html">Elements</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--================End Header Menu Area =================-->
    <!--================Footer Area =================-->

        @RenderBody()

        <footer class="footr_area">
            <div class="footer_widget_area">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row footer_widget_inner">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                            <aside class="f_widget f_about_widget">
                                <img src="~/Recursos/img/footer-logo.png" alt="">
                                <p>Cras ex mauris, ornare eget pretium sit amet, dignissim et turpis. Nunc nec maximus dui, vel suscipit dolor. Donec elementum velit a orci facilisis rutrum.</p>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                            <aside class="f_widget f_insta_widget">
                                <div class="f_title">
                                    <h3>Instagram</h3>
                                </div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-6.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-7.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Recursos/img/instagram/ins-8.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                            <aside class="f_widget f_subs_widget">
                                <div class="f_title">
                                    <h3>Subscribe to newsletter</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your e-mail address here" aria-label="Your e-mail address here">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary submit_btn" type="button">Subscribe</button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </aside>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_copyright">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="float-sm-left">
                        <h5>
                            <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
                            Copyright &copy;
                            <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
                            <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-sm-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-behance"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <!--================End Footer Area =================-->
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="~/Recursos/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Rev slider js -->
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/revolution/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Extra plugin css -->
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/counterup/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/counterup/apear.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/counterup/countto.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/magnify-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/circle-bar/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/vendors/circle-bar/plugins.js"></script>

        <script src="~/Recursos/js/circle-active.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Recursos/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes copiar el codigo que tiene el archivo `_ViewStart.cshtml`? Lo más probable es que el error este ahí

Comment: Claro, esto es lo que sale:

 @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

Comment: Hice la prueba y me funciona.. lo único que se me ocurre es que estés apuntando a otra vista, la cual no tiene el `@RenderBody`; asegúrate de eso primero! :)

Comment: Acabo de revisar si de alguna forma estaba llamando a otro layout, pero no :(

Comment: Mmmm... prueba agregando otro layout, especificando `@RenderBody` en el y apuntando en el `_ViewStart` hacia ese layout para que confirmes que no ese el problema; lo otro que se me ocurre es que al momento de "_correr_" el programa desde Visual Studio la pestaña activa sea un `Layout` que no tiene ese `tag`, como `Error.cshtml` o similar, aunque realmente no creo que pase por ahí =/